Jib Maven Plugin: 401 Unauthorized Error When Pushing Docker Image to Docker Hub
I cannot push a Docker image using the Jib Maven Plugin. I’m repeatedly getting a 401 Unauthorized error. I have not changed much, but the day before I got a 416 error. Here’s a quick summary of the problem:
Error message when using:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>korfballteamapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>KorfballTeamAPI</name>
    <description>KorfballTeamAPI</description>

    <organization>
        <name>GlasgowKorfball</name>
        <url>https://GlasgowKorfball.com</url>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <docker.username>rsmithuchot1</docker.username>
        <start-class>org.example.korfballteamapi.KorfballTeamApiApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    ....Rest of POM

    <build>
        <plugins>
            ... rest of plugins
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>eclipse-temurin:22</image>
                        <platforms>
                            <platform>
                                <architecture>arm64</architecture>
                                <os>linux</os>
                            </platform>
                            <platform>
                                <architecture>amd64</architecture>
                                <os>linux</os>
                            </platform>
                        </platforms>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>docker.io/rsmithucot1/korfball-api</image>
                        <tags>
                            <tag>latest</tag>
                        </tags>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Error message:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.3:build (default) on project korfballteamapi: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry-1.docker.io/thisisanewimage' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help: Unauthorized for registry-1.docker.io/thisisanewimage: 401 Unauthorized.
[ERROR] HEAD https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/thisisanewimage/blobs/sha256:0806d5dbd9524f498cca7b9bea84c32bef6050eb04603092302d155b92fb411e

Error message when using:

    <organization>
        <name>GlasgowKorfball</name>
        <url>https://GlasgowKorfball.com</url>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <docker.username>rsmithuchot1</docker.username>
        <start-class>org.example.korfballteamapi.KorfballTeamApiApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    enter code here

... rest of the POM

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>eclipse-temurin:22</image>
                        <platforms>
                            <platform>
                                <architecture>arm64</architecture>
                                <os>linux</os>
                            </platform>
                            <platform>
                                <architecture>amd64</architecture>
                                <os>linux</os>
                            </platform>
                        </platforms>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>docker.io/${docker.username}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</image>
                        <tags>
                            <tag>latest</tag>
                        </tags>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

Error message:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.3:build (default) on project korfballteamapi: 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
[ERROR] PATCH https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rsmithuchot1/korfballteamapi/blobs/uploads/ecfb7fe9-bf7b-4705-a25e-f2c4f9125e43?_state=GViHxJxiULvlBx3YP1PH-1qcnMEZ7KsgxbHLYqqhK2J7Ik5hbWUiOiJyc21pdGh1Y2hvdDEva29yZmJhbGx0ZWFtYXBpIiwiVVVJRCI6ImVjZmI3ZmU5LWJmN2ItNDcwNS1hMjVlLWYyYzRmOTEyNWU0MyIsIk9mZnNldCI6MCwiU3RhcnRlZEF0IjoiMjAyNC0wOS0xMlQxMjowMDo1MC4wMDY1MDE1NTJaIn0%3D
[ERROR] {"errors":[{"code":"RANGE_INVALID","message":"invalid content range"}]}

Credentials configuration:
Here is the relevant part of my config.json:
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "REDACTED_BASE64_ENCODED_CREDENTIALS"
    },
    "https://index.docker.io/v2/": {
      "auth": "REDACTED_BASE64_ENCODED_CREDENTIALS"
    }
  },
  "currentContext": "desktop-linux",
  "plugins": {
    "debug": {
      "hooks": "exec"
    },
    "scout": {
      "hooks": "pull,buildx build"
    }
  },
  "features": {
    "hooks": "true"
  }
}

What I’ve tried:

Re-authenticated with Docker Hub: I used docker login to ensure my credentials are up-to-date.

Verified credential encoding: The credentials appear to be base64-encoded correctly.

Checked Docker Hub URL: Confirmed that the registry URL is correct.

I downloaded and pushed an image: I downloaded a random image and pushed it to docker fine so that I can push from my command line.


Additional information:

Jib Maven Plugin Version: 3.4.3

Docker Config Location: C:\Users\richa\.docker\config.json

Image Name: thisisanewimage

Repository: "https://index.docker.io/v1/" or "https://index.docker.io/v2/"


Question:
What might be causing the 401 Unauthorized error when using Jib to push the Docker image or the 416 Request Range Not Satisfiable? Does it relate to when the image for the tumerin:22 is being pulled? Are there any specific issues with how credentials are managed or how Jib interacts with Docker Hub that I should be aware of? I do not understand why these credentials (the ones automatically generated by docker when logging in in the config file) are insufficient if I log in to the terminal to docker.
